# Why Cant I write the sign '&' in my app's name? - corona

Tags: lua, apk, coronasdk, sign

When I write the sign '&' in my app's name it terns into '_' . 
someone knows why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Try `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0):

For people following up with this, the latest daily build of Corona SDK (and probably the most recent public build) will solve this issue. Corona Labs has to produce operating safe file names. The name on the device should come from your build screen settings.